# PHP- RoxyFileMan set FILES_ROOT path dynamically

Tags: php, roxy-fileman

i am working with the roxyfileman for tiny MCE, i integrated the Roxyfileman with the tinyMCE successfully and it is working fine,

But based on the users i want to list the directory in the File Manager list. But i am lagging of how to assign the value in conf.json for FILES_ROOT dynamically for the respective user

**For example:**

--Uploads/userupload/{userid}-{username}
{userid}-{username} is a folder generated dynamically

I need to assign this path in the FILES_ROOT in Fileman

```
{
"FILES_ROOT":          "/uploads/userupload/",
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "",
"THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH":   "140",
"THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT":  "120",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH": "100",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT":"100",
"MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH":     "1000",
"MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT":    "1000",
"INTEGRATION":         "tinymce4",
"DIRLIST":             "php/dirtree.php",
"CREATEDIR":           "php/createdir.php",
"DELETEDIR":           "php/deletedir.php",
"MOVEDIR":             "php/movedir.php",
"COPYDIR":             "php/copydir.php",
"RENAMEDIR":           "php/renamedir.php",
"FILESLIST":           "php/fileslist.php",
"UPLOAD":              "php/upload.php",
"DOWNLOAD":            "php/download.php",
"DOWNLOADDIR":         "php/downloaddir.php",
"DELETEFILE":          "php/deletefile.php",
"MOVEFILE":            "php/movefile.php",
"COPYFILE":            "php/copyfile.php",
"RENAMEFILE":          "php/renamefile.php",
"GENERATETHUMB":       "php/thumb.php",
"DEFAULTVIEW":         "list",
"FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS":   "zip js jsp jsb mhtml mht xhtml xht php phtml php3 php4 php5 phps shtml jhtml pl sh py cgi exe application gadget hta cpl msc jar vb jse ws wsf wsc wsh ps1 ps2 psc1 psc2 msh msh1 msh2 inf reg scf msp scr dll msi vbs bat com pif cmd vxd cpl htpasswd htaccess",
"ALLOWED_UPLOADS":     "",
"FILEPERMISSIONS":     "0644",
"DIRPERMISSIONS":      "0755",
"LANG":                "auto",
"DATEFORMAT":          "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
"OPEN_LAST_DIR":       "yes"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have do define a Session Var first. For Example you write this in your config File:

```
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "myRoxySession"
```

Now you have to Setup your Code to write into this Session Var the right path before you start Roxy File Manager. In PHP for Example:

```
$_SESSION["myRoxySession"] = "Uploads/userupload/{userid}-{username} {userid}-{username}"
```

This should work.

Comment: There is a conf.json in the Root Directory of File Manager. The Session you have to set in your Application Code

Comment: can you guide me what sholud i do? sholud i set FILES_ROOT first ? and then set SESSION_PATH_KEY? i do this  in my admin page which i insert image to my content i set $_SESSION['name']=ROOT_PATH."estekhdami/agahi_content_images/";

Comment: You first set "SESSION_PATH_KEY" in the Roxy File Manager Config File to a Name: e.g: "myDynamicFolder". Than you Roxy File Manager will use not "FILES_ROOT" but the value of the session. OK?

Comment: and then set the 'myDynamicFolder' session with absolute path? i sholud try again.

Comment: yes: $_SESSION["myDynamicFolder"]='/path/to/the/folder';

Comment: tnx work what you say and asked. but I want image save in db with absolute path, is it possible? for example my site root path is "/1hezar/" and file man is in /1hezar/admin" and i want save image in "/1hezar/images/" but when image saved in db the adress is "images/etc.jpg" do you know how can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

First open fileman directory `conf.json` sample config

```
"FILES_ROOT":          "", // empty
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "dynamic-user-folder" // $_session["dynamic-user-folder"]
```

Save close config file. Now open php file add code,

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
};

$firma_slug = "/alpc-bilgisayar-aladag-n1qux"; // sample user dynamic folder name

$_SESSION["dynamic-user-folder"] = "/firma".$firma_slug;
```

sample folder name `firma`, `/` char root directory

> result : `root/firma/alpc-bilgisayar-aladag-n1qux // upload directory`.

Thanks user3265427